# Plain Text Field Word Wrap CSS isn't working in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, infopath, multiline-text-field

I'm utilizing the following CSS styling in order to word wrap the text in plain-text multi-line text fields in an InfoPath form (2013).  Here's the code I'm working with:

```
textarea{
    white - space: pre-line !important;
```

}

It doesn't seem to be working.  Is my code above incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property is **white-space** (no spaces in the name). [Documentation here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)